# How to populate a table using a rule replacement

Tags: list-manipulation, data-structures

I am trying to populate the rows and columns of a table by using a rule replacment.

To generate a table that looks like this
[image]

For example Sc would be row 1, column 1.

An example of a record looks like this

```
 rawData = Import["H:\\allresults.json"]


record = {19, 60, "Ag", "Ag", "19Ag@60Ag_npo: -186.503305 by solar<br> \
19Ag@60Ag_bnp: -180.812004 by solar<br> O_sng:-8.032213 by \
marco<br>", "-1.675194475", "Binding Energy", "solar"}
```

Then I extract the relevant entries with some functions (there is probably a more elegant way to to do this)

```
getRow[resultVector_] := resultVector[[3]];
getColumn[resultVector_] := resultVector[[4]];
getResult[resultVector_] := resultVector[[5]];
getResultType[resultVector_] := resultVector[[7]];
```

For example

```
getRow[record]
```

gives

```
Out[41] = Ag
```

I have a list of replacemnt rules

```
elementList = {"Sc" -> 1, "Ti" -> 2, "V" -> 3, "Cr" -> 4, "Mn" -> 5, 
  "Fe" -> 6, "Co" -> 7, "Ni" -> 8, "Cu" -> 9, "Zn" -> 10, "Y" -> 11, 
  "Zr" -> 12, "Nb" -> 13, "Mo" -> 14, "Tc" -> 15, "Ru" -> 16, 
  "Rh" -> 17, "Pd" -> 18, "Ag" -> 19, "Cd" -> 20, "Lu" -> 21, 
  "Hf" -> 22, "Ta" -> 23, "W" -> 24, "Re" -> 25, "Os" -> 26, 
  "Ir" -> 27, "Pt" -> 28, "Au" -> 29, "Hg" -> 30}
```

I would like to build a table where the location in the table gets identified, and the corresponding result gets put into that location of the table.

For example Ag, Ag (row, column) should put "-1.675194475" in location (19,19) (row, column) of a table.

Is there a better way to do this than with replacement rules?

---

Update:

Here is my current implementation to see all my data:

```
elementList = {"Sc" -> 1, "Ti" -> 2, "V" -> 3, "Cr" -> 4, "Mn" -> 5, 
 "Fe" -> 6, "Co" -> 7, "Ni" -> 8, "Cu" -> 9, "Zn" -> 10, "Y" -> 11, 
  "Zr" -> 12, "Nb" -> 13, "Mo" -> 14, "Tc" -> 15, "Ru" -> 16, 
  "Rh" -> 17, "Pd" -> 18, "Ag" -> 19, "Cd" -> 20, "Lu" -> 21, 
  "Hf" -> 22, "Ta" -> 23, "W" -> 24, "Re" -> 25, "Os" -> 26, 
  "Ir" -> 27, "Pt" -> 28, "Au" -> 29, "Hg" -> 30};
```

I create lists of data for different particle sizes and energy types

```
data = Import["H:\\allresults.json"];
atoms32 = Select[data, StringCases[#[[1]], "32"] != {} &];
atoms79 = Select[data, StringCases[#[[1]], "60"] != {} &];
atoms32Binding = 
  Select[atoms32, StringCases[#[[1]], "Binding"] != {} &];
atoms32Cohesive = 
  Select[atoms32, StringCases[#[[1]], "Cohesive"] != {} &] ;
atoms79Binding = 
  Select[atoms79, StringCases[#[[1]], "Binding"] != {} &];
atoms79Cohesive = 
  Select[atoms79, StringCases[#[[1]], "Cohesive"] != {} &];
mat = Outer[List, elements, elements];
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I intend to do more energy calculations of different types in the future (vacancy formation energy etc).  Is it possible to write it such that the  data is automatically partitioned out into lists for each size and type?

```
rules79Binding = 
  Cases[atoms79Binding, {__, "M1" -> e1_, "M2" -> e2_, __, 
     "result" -> val_, __} :> {e1, e2} -> 
     ToExpression@val, \[Infinity]];
rules79Cohesive = 
  Cases[atoms79Cohesive, {__, "M1" -> e1_, "M2" -> e2_, __, 
     "result" -> val_, __} :> {e1, e2} -> 
     ToExpression@val, \[Infinity]];
rules32Binding = 
  Cases[atoms32Binding, {__, "M1" -> e1_, "M2" -> e2_, __, 
     "result" -> val_, __} :> {e1, e2} -> 
     ToExpression@val, \[Infinity]];
rules32Cohesive = 
  Cases[atoms32Cohesive, {__, "M1" -> e1_, "M2" -> e2_, __, 
     "result" -> val_, __} :> {e1, e2} -> 
     ToExpression@val, \[Infinity]];
```

This also suffers from exactly the same repetitive line with the only thing that changes between the lines is the list.

Finally I plot all the data

```
ArrayPlot[mat /. rules79Binding /. {_, _} -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, Red}, #] &), 
 ColorRules -> {0 -> White}, Mesh -> True, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> ({#, #} &@Transpose@{Range@Length@elements, elements}),
  PlotRangePadding -> None, ImageSize -> 500, 
 PlotLabel -> "19M1@60M2 Binding Energy"]
ArrayPlot[mat /. rules79Cohesive /. {_, _} -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, Red}, #] &), 
 ColorRules -> {0 -> White}, Mesh -> True, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> ({#, #} &@Transpose@{Range@Length@elements, elements}),
  PlotRangePadding -> None, ImageSize -> 500, 
 PlotLabel -> "19M1@60M2 Cohesive Energy"]
ArrayPlot[mat /. rules32Binding /. {_, _} -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, Red}, #] &), 
 ColorRules -> {0 -> White}, Mesh -> True, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> ({#, #} &@Transpose@{Range@Length@elements, elements}),
  PlotRangePadding -> None, ImageSize -> 500, 
 PlotLabel -> "6M1@32M2 Binding Energy"]
ArrayPlot[mat /. rules32Cohesive /. {_, _} -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, Red}, #] &), 
 ColorRules -> {0 -> White}, Mesh -> True, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> ({#, #} &@Transpose@{Range@Length@elements, elements}),
  PlotRangePadding -> None, ImageSize -> 500, 
 PlotLabel -> "6M1@32M2 Cohesive Energy"]
```

I have not put pictures up of each plot so that I do not make the post too long.

Also, How can I map specific numerical values over color gradients.  For example, for the binding energies, {-1,-2} blends through green.  {-2,-3} blends through yellow {-3,-5}, blends through orange, {-5, -10} blends through red, and {-10, infinity} is black.

Comment: Your `record` needs an extra `{`. I couldn't add it as I can only edit with a minimum of 6 characters.

Comment: Your problem might be more tractable if you do a proper `Import[]` of your source data. Can you maybe give at least an example file we can pull data from?

Comment: Can you also explain what the problem with using the replacement is? Is it taking too long this way or is it not doing something that you would otherwise like it to do?

Comment: Here is a link to the data.  It is in JSON format. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5gGZ4-SD7-Zb1Q2ZUtUUmJXNHc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JonathanShock I don't know how to do the rule replacement.  The table shown is on the web. and my link has the data that generated it.  I want to load the data into a table to both reproduce the chart, and to be able to perform calculations on the  data.  Like make plots of the values across a row for example.

Comment: I presume you mean (19,19) for Ag,Ag?

Comment: Yes that is right.  I edited the main post

Comment: And if you are looking for cohesive energy then you actually want that result to be `-172.687486`, not `-1.675...`?

Comment: I am looking for binding energy with this particular record.  The data set has information for generating several of these tables.

Comment: updated question. and deleted the answer to my own question.  Thanks for all the help so far guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will take all of the data that you want from the json file and give you a `Table` that you can use as you wish. Is this what was wanted?

```
elementList = {"Sc" -> 1, "Ti" -> 2, "V" -> 3, "Cr" -> 4, "Mn" -> 5, 
"Fe" -> 6, "Co" -> 7, "Ni" -> 8, "Cu" -> 9, "Zn" -> 10, "Y" -> 11, 
"Zr" -> 12, "Nb" -> 13, "Mo" -> 14, "Tc" -> 15, "Ru" -> 16, 
"Rh" -> 17, "Pd" -> 18, "Ag" -> 19, "Cd" -> 20, "Lu" -> 21, 
"Hf" -> 22, "Ta" -> 23, "W" -> 24, "Re" -> 25, "Os" -> 26, 
"Ir" -> 27, "Pt" -> 28, "Au" -> 29, "Hg" -> 30};
```

Import the data

```
data = Import["directory/allresults.json"];
```

Take only the data which includes the binding energy results.

```
binding = Select[data, StringCases[#[[1]], "Binding"] != {} &];
```

Take this data and take the elements which correspond to the x and y axes in the figure (ie. the two elements) along with the result (which has to be converted to an `Expression` rather than a `String`

```
dataall = {#[[1]], #[[2]], 
  ToExpression[#[[3]]]} & /@ ({"M1", "M2", "result"} /. #[[2]] & /@
    binding) /. elementList;
```

This should be the table you are looking for (or at least a list of the data you want).

Edit:

In response to the comment, you can populate a table in the way that you want with:

```
tab=Table[Cases[dataall,{m,n,_}][[;; , 3]],{m,1,30},{n,1,30}] // MatrixForm
```

However, you should note that there are sometimes two entries for a single combination of elements.

If you want the elements only at the end of the file (as requested in the comment) you can call:

```
Table[
  With[{x = Cases[dataall, {m, n, _}][[;; , 3]]}, 
    If[x === {}, 0, x[[-1]]]], 
  {m, 1, 30}, {n, 1, 30}] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: If it is possible, can the data be ordered such that `dataall[[19]][[19]]`  would give `-172.687486` ?

Comment: @olliepower, there are two problems. One is that that appears to be the cohesive energy, the other is that there are two entries for binding energy (and also two for cohesive energy) for (for instance) Ag, Ag. I have however added this as an edit to the answer.

Comment: I see.  I just noticed you edited your answer.  If there are two entries it should take the entry closest to the end of the data file. .  I am editing my above comment to read for the binding energy.

Comment: That is now implemented as well.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer a slightly different approach to Jonathan's, and I believe it is simpler and more in line with the spirit of using rule replacements for getting things done. First, note that since you're dealing with elements in the periodic table, which are finite and small in number (and pairs of those), you can easily generate your matrix of pairs of elements and apply rules to those. So, taking the list of elements and the data (where `elementList` is from the question),

```
elements = List @@@ elementList // Transpose // First;
mat = Outer[List, elements, elements];
```

you can construct the replacement rules from the JSON structure as

```
data = Import["~/Downloads/Chrome/allresults.json"];
rules = Cases[data, {__, "M1" -> e1_, "M2" -> e2_, __, "result" -> val_, __} :> 
    {e1, e2} -> ToExpression@val, ∞];
```

and simply use rules to replace the matrix entries and display the result:

```
ArrayPlot[
    mat /. rules /. {_, _} -> 0,
    ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, Red}, #] &), 
    ColorRules -> {0 -> White}, Mesh -> True, Frame -> True,
    FrameTicks -> ({#, #} &@Transpose@{Range@Length@elements, elements}),
    PlotRangePadding -> None, ImageSize -> 500
]
```

[image]

Comment: I get errors when i tried to use  your code.  `Outer::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 2 in Outer[List,element,element]. >>' Outer::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 2 in Outer[List,element,element]. >> Outer::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 2 in Outer[List,element,element]. >>

Comment: I will trouble shoot in the morning.  I must go to sleep.

Comment: @olliepower I don't get that error. You must not have defined `element` as I've done it.

Comment: where you define `element`  I defined `elementList` exactly as I did above, and I have copy pasted your code.  I really like the fancy table it made!

Comment: @olliepower So does it work now or do you still get an error?

Comment: I never got it to work exactly as you had it.  However the bit of code to generate the table was very useful!  Thanks!

Comment: @olliepower I made a typo in writing it here — I had `element` instead of `elements`. I've fixed it now; if you copy the above and try it, it should run correctly

Comment: it works.  This is morphing into a solution I am becoming very happy with.  I'm going to make a few more tweaks and post back.  How should I update the question/post after all my tweaks?